# Copy cell value to another sheet for matching value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets: "Data Base" and "Adendas". One has changes records and the other works as a database.

"Data Base" has these columns among others:

- Name (Column D)
- Location (Column K)
- Hours (Column L)
- Vehicle (Column M)

"Adendas" has:

- Name (Column D)
- Change Type (Column M)
- Location (Column N)
- Hours (Column O)
- Vehicle (Column P)
- From (Column Q)
- Change Confirmation (Column R)

Observations:

Changes are added to the 'Adendas' sheet with a from date specified. When the date matches today, it is supposed to copy the correspondent information depending the type of change from 'Adendas' to the matching name in 'Data Base'

- **The Data Base sheet look like this:**

[image: Data Base Sheet]

- **Adendas Sheet:**

[image: Adendas Sheet]

For example, today 04/25/2022, it should move the vehicle information from **Column P** in Adendas to **Column M** in Data Base for **Name2** and then apply a true value to the Confirmation box in Adenda's **Column R**

Result should look like this:

Data Base
[image: Result]
Adendas
[image: Result2]

After lot of search and investigation, I managed to create the following code which works for the date and checkbox part but I can't manage to apply the change to the matching name value as it should since it's copying it but at a random cell.

```js
function parse_worker(employee) {
    /* Given a row from the spreadsheet, parse the data into a javascript object. */

    if (typeof(employee) == 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    let trabajador = {};

    trabajador.nombre = employee[3];
    trabajador.tipo = employee[12];
    trabajador.location = employee[13];
    trabajador.hours = employee[14];
    trabajador.vehicle = employee[15];
    trabajador.fecha = employee[16];
    trabajador.cambio = employee[17];

    return trabajador;
};

function are_dates_equal(date1, date2) {
    /* Returns true if the two dates are equal, false otherwise. 
    
    It only compares the day, the month and the year. Time is not considered.
    */

    return date1.getUTCDate() == date2.getUTCDate() && date1.getUTCMonth() == date2.getUTCMonth() && date1.getUTCFullYear() == date2.getUTCFullYear();
}

function try_to_copy_data() {
    /* Iterate over the rows in the spreadsheet and make the corresponding change if it's time to do it. */

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Adendas');
    var sourceRows = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Base');
    var targetRows = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow() - 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();


    sourceRows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        /* Copy's the data to the given employee if it's time to do it and the change type matches. */

        // Exit the function if the employee has no date.
        let is_date_set = row[16] !== '';
        if (!is_date_set) {
            return;
        }

        let worker = parse_worker(row);
        var now = new Date();

        Logger.log(now.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'UTC'}));
        Logger.log(worker.fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'UTC'}));

        // Exit the function if is not time to make the change
        if (!are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha)) {
            return;
        }

        // Exit the function if change has already made
        if (worker.cambio === true) {
            return;
        }

        if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Vehículo"){
            targetSheet.getRange(i+2,[13]).setValue(worker.vehicle);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Centro de Trabajo"){
            targetSheet.getRange(i+2,[11]).setValue(worker.vehicle);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Horas Contrato"){
            targetSheet.getRange(i+2,[12]).setValue(worker.vehicle);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else {
            Logger.log("Error! Not a valid change.");
        }

    })
}
try_to_copy_data();
```

The idea was to use the general knowledge on how to copy the value automatically and then adapt it to the positioning thing but I'm not even close to figure out how to do it.

**EDIT: Final working code thanks to Yuri's help**

```js
function parse_worker(employee) {
    /* Given a row from the spreadsheet, parse the data into a javascript object. */

    if (typeof(employee) == 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    let trabajador = {};

    trabajador.nombre = employee[3];
    trabajador.tipo = employee[12];
    trabajador.location = employee[13];
    trabajador.hours = employee[14];
    trabajador.vehicle = employee[15];
    trabajador.fecha = employee[16];
    trabajador.cambio = employee[17];

    return trabajador;
};

function are_dates_equal(date1, date2) {
    /* Returns true if the two dates are equal, false otherwise. 
    
    It only compares the day, the month and the year. Time is not considered.
    */

    return date1.getUTCDate() == date2.getUTCDate() && date1.getUTCMonth() == date2.getUTCMonth() && date1.getUTCFullYear() == date2.getUTCFullYear();
}

function try_to_copy_data() {
    /* Iterate over the rows in the spreadsheet and make the corresponding change if it's time to do it. */

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Adendas');
    var sourceRows = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Base');
    var targetRows = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow() - 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var targetNames = targetRows.map(e => e[3]);



    sourceRows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        /* Copy's the data to the given employee if it's time to do it and the change type matches. */

        // Exit the function if the employee has no date.
        let is_date_set = row[16] !== '';
        if (!is_date_set) {
            return;
        }

        let worker = parse_worker(row);
        var now = new Date();
        var row_index = targetNames.indexOf(worker.nombre);


        Logger.log(now.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'UTC'}));
        Logger.log(worker.fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'UTC'}));

        // Exit the function if is not time to make the change
        if (!are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha)) {
            return;
        }

        // Exit the function if change has already made
        if (worker.cambio === true) {
            return;
        }

        if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Vehículo"){
            targetSheet.getRange(row_index+2,13).setValue(worker.vehicle);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Centro de Trabajo"){
            targetSheet.getRange(row_index+2,11).setValue(worker.location);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else if (are_dates_equal(now, worker.fecha) && worker.tipo === "Horas Contrato"){
            targetSheet.getRange(row_index+2,12).setValue(worker.hours);
            sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,[18]).setValue(true);
        } else {
            Logger.log("Error! Not a valid change.");
        }

    })
}
try_to_copy_data();
```

Comment: It would be better if you share your spreadsheet. Or, at the very least, include the column letters into your screenshots.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Sorry! I added the columns to the screenshots + outcome screenshots on how should it look

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of your question and provide a simple [mcve] that reproduces the problem for us in a well defined way.   Normally, your final script does not make a good [mcve] you will probably need to create one.  If you are unwilling to spend the time to do so then you are simply telling us that your time is more valuable than ours and we most likely will not agree with you.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for your feedback. Even though the post has a lots of things included, if you read it it actually comes to one issue or question which is that I'm currently copying the information but not where's supposed to be on the targetSheet, probably something to do with the .setvalue I'm ussing while everything else runs perfectly. I can just have here the part of the code that's presenting an issue but I thought that having everything explained and detailed would be better for anyone trying to answer it since it provides the full context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it should be something like this:

```
function try_to_copy_data() {

  var now = new Date();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Adendas');
  var sourceRows = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Base');
  var [header, ...targetRows] = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetNames = targetRows.map(e => e[3]);

  sourceRows.forEach((row, i) => {

    let worker = parse_worker(row);
    if (worker.ok == true) return;
    if (!are_dates_equal(now, worker.date)) return;

    var row_index = targetNames.indexOf(worker.name);

    if (worker.location != '') targetRows[row_index][10] = worker.location;
    if (worker.hours != '')    targetRows[row_index][11] = worker.hours;
    if (worker.vehicle != '')  targetRows[row_index][12] = worker.vehicle;

    sourceSheet.getRange('R' + (i+2)).check();
  })

  var table = [header, ...targetRows];
  targetSheet.clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length)
    .setValues(table);
}

function parse_worker(row) {
  let worker = {
    name:     row[3],
    type:     row[12],
    location: row[13],
    hours:    row[14],
    vehicle:  row[15],
    date:     row[16],
    ok:       row[17],
  }
  return worker;
}

function are_dates_equal(date1, date2) {
  return date1.getUTCDate() == date2.getUTCDate() &&
    date1.getUTCMonth() == date2.getUTCMonth() &&
    date1.getUTCFullYear() == date2.getUTCFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried your version but I got an error saying that date2.getUTCDate was not a function but using what you provided allowed me to adapt the code into mine and got it working perfectly. Again, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad if it works. Let me know if you need any help.